# Keep user env variables executing gksu

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have a program in c/gtk which is opened with gksu. The problem is that when I get the environment variable $HOME with getenv("HOME") it returns "root" obviously. I would like to know if there is a way to know who was the user that executed the gksu or the way to get his environmental variables.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The common wisdom is to do the opposite: GTK is not supposed to run as root, so your GTK program could run from the non-root user and start a "command-line" root-setuid executable; starting a GTK application from `sudo` or `gksu` is a bad idea.

Comment: I am doing a program that makes ioctl calls. So that can only be done by the superuser. If I want to allow that other users could execute, I have to pass root privileges. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The common way to code that is to separate the app into two application, one providing the GTK interface, and the other (setuid) which does the actual thing (and communicate with pipes or some other IPC with the GTK interface).

Comment: Setuid doesn't work for the ioctl call. I've tested it. The other way sounds a little hard. Could you explain a little more plase?

Comment: seteuid enables you to run as root (or some other user or group) some given executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the man page. Use `gksu -k command...` to preserve the environment (in particular, `PATH` and `HOME`).

Or, like Lewis Richard Phillip C indicated, you can use `gksu env PATH="$PATH" HOME="$HOME" command...` to reset the environment variables for the command. (The logic is that the parent shell, the one run with user privileges, substitutes the variables, and `env` re-sets them when superuser privileges have been attained.)

If your application should only be run with root privileges, you can write a launcher script -- just like many other applications do. The script itself is basically

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gksu -k /path/to/your/application "$@"
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gksu env PATH="$PATH" HOME="$HOME" /path/to/your/application "$@"
```

The script is installed in `/usr/bin`, and your application as `/usr/bin/yourapp-bin` or `/usr/lib/yourapp/yourapp`. The `exec` means that the command *replaces* the shell; i.e. nothing after the `exec` command will ever be executed (unless the application or command cannot be executed at all) -- and most importantly, there will not be an extra shell in memory while your application is begin executed.

While Linux and other POSIX-like systems do have a notion of *effective* identity (defining the operations an application may do) and *real* identity (defining the user that is doing the operation), `gksu` modifies all identities. In particular, while `getuid()` returns the real user ID for example for set-UID binaries, it will return zero ("root") when `gksu` is used.

Therefore, the above launch script is the recommended method to solve your problem. It is also a common one; run

```
file -L /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* | sed -ne '/shell/ s|:.*$||p' | xargs -r grep -lie launcher -e '^exec /'
```

to see which commands are (or declare themselves to be) launcher scripts on your system, or

```
file -L /bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/* | sed -ne '/shell/ s|:.*$||p' | xargs -r grep -lie gksu
```

to see which ones use `gksu` explicitly. There is no harm in adopting a known good approach.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could assign the values of these environment vars to standard variables, then execute gksu exporting the vars after gkSU... By defining these after the gkSU using && to bind together your executions, so that you essentially execute using cloned environment variables...

A better question is why do this at all? I realize you are wanting to keep some folders, but am not sure why as any files created as root, would have to be globally writable, probably using umask, or you would have to manually revise permissions or change ownership... This is such a bad Idea!

Please check out https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables , http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-export-command/ & https://serverfault.com/questions/62178/how-to-specify-roots-environment-variable